# Excel - Return Keyword and following word in string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have the following formula:

```
=MID(A2,FIND(B1,A2),12)
```

- `A2` = "something boring about something boring #Fault Dan"
- `B1` = "#Fault"

My aim is to search cell `A1` and find the keyword "#Fault", and then return this and the following word, which should be someone's name. The above works fine in one example, but if the name is more than three characters, it cuts off.

What method can I use to confirm the number of characters from the start of the keyword to the end of the word that follows the keyword, and put this in place of the current "12"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the third criterion of find to find the first space after the `#`:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("#",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#",A1))-FIND("#",A1))
```

EDIT

```
=MID(A1,FIND("#",A1),IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#",A1))+1)-FIND("#",A1),LEN(A1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Apolgies, I'm looking to return : #Fault Dan  How would I find the second space after '#'?  Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: @DanBreakwell see edit

Comment: Thanks Scott, But this is still returning only #Fault.

Comment: @DanBreakwell the only way that happens is if you have two or more spaces in between the two words.

Comment: You spotted my mistake! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You spotted my mistake! Many thanks for your help!